# Function from backend returns json object, but when received it is also an array

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to create a function that will retrieve some objects for my in a very specific format. Here's the code for that function:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            data: err
          });
    }
    
    connection.query("select cqq.* from coursequizquestions as cqq, coursequiz as cq where cqq.quiz = ? and cq.quizTitle = cqq.quiz and cq.course in (select courseUUID from courses where courseName = ?)", [quizName, courseName], function(err1, results) {
        connection.release();
        if (err1) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                data: err1
          });
        }
        
        let r = {};
        
        for(const i in results) {
            r[results[i].quizQuestion] = results[i];
        }
        
        return res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                data: r
            });
    });
})
```

Where "pool" is an SQL pool object created using the `mysql.createpool` function. When I request this data, I'm expecting to get something that looks like this:

```
{
"Question 1": {
    "id": 1,
    "quiz": "Vue.js Introduction",
    "quizQuestion": "Question 1",
    "quizAnswer": null,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17T04:00:00.000Z",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "questionScore": 50,
    "questionOrder": 1,
    "type": "Input"
},
"Question 2": {
    "id": 2,
    "quiz": "Vue.js Introduction",
    "quizQuestion": "Question 2",
    "quizAnswer": null,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17T04:00:00.000Z",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "questionScore": 50,
    "questionOrder": 2,
    "type": "Input"
}
}
```

and it seems like it is exactly what I get when monitoring from the backend. When it arrives on the frontend, however, I get this:

```
{
"0": {
    "questionOrder": 1,
    "type": "input",
    "quizQuestion": "0",
    "questionScore": 50,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "choices": {}
},
"1": {
    "questionOrder": 2,
    "type": "input",
    "quizQuestion": "1",
    "questionScore": 50,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "choices": {}
},
"Question 1": {
    "id": 1,
    "quiz": "Vue.js Introduction",
    "quizQuestion": "Question 1",
    "quizAnswer": null,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17T04:00:00.000Z",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "questionScore": 50,
    "questionOrder": 1,
    "type": "Input"
},
"Question 2": {
    "id": 2,
    "quiz": "Vue.js Introduction",
    "quizQuestion": "Question 2",
    "quizAnswer": null,
    "dateCreated": "2021-06-17T04:00:00.000Z",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "videoUUID": null,
    "questionScore": 50,
    "questionOrder": 2,
    "type": "Input"
}
}
```

There are added keys that are integers as if my object was an array. I don't see this type of output at any other endpoint. Oddly, when I log this object (in Google Chrome) the integer keys do not appear in the preview, but they do appear when I expand the entire object. Also, when I loop over this object using this code:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/courses/getQuestions?quizName=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("quiz_title").value) + "&courseName=" + encodeURI(course)).then(j => j.json())
    .then(j => {
        console.log(j.data);
       questionData = j.data;
        let questionList = document.getElementById("question-list");
        questionList.innerHTML = "";
        for (const i in sortDict(questionData, "questionOrder")) {
            makeQuestionElement(i, questionList);
        }
}
```

then it only loops over the integer keys, essentially ignoring the portion of the output that was expected. Is there any insight as to what's happening here?

Comment: Use the network tab in DevTools to see exactly what is coming on the wire - if it comes with integer keys, then troubleshoot the server code.

Comment: It appears that my expected output comes in on the wire according to the network tab. I'll troubleshoot my client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem - It turns out that my `sortDict` function was implemented incorrectly. Instead of returning an object with sorted keys, it returned a list of keys in the sorted order. The reason that the keys were populating like an array is that I was actually iterating through an array when running my loop. I've adjusted the code with this information in mind, and the problem was fixed.